# Is Non Non Biyori's location based on a real one?

Tags: tourism, non-non-biyori

I have seen the photos at the end of the Non Non Biyori episodes and they seem to resemble places from within the anime. I wonder if all those photographed places belong to roughly the same location.

In other words: **Is the Asahigaoka village in Non Non Biyori based on a real one?**

And if yes: **Where is this located?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The town of Asahigaoka is not explicitly based on any single real location. Of course, some location scouting in the countryside was performed for the sake of realism.<sup>1</sup> Most anime these days engage in this activity (called "location hunting" / ロケハン) when appropriate - e.g. when they are set in modern Japan or something that looks like it.<sup>2</sup>

That said, the school the students in Non Non Biyori attend *is* apparently based on a real school: Ogawa Elementary's Shimosato Branch School<sup>3</sup> in [Ogawa, Saitama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogawa,_Saitama).<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> See [this blog post](http://anicobin.ldblog.jp/archives/35098549.html) (JP), and in particular [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Es5wX.jpg) (JP), taken from an interview with people on the production staff.

<sup>2</sup> Of course, some shows *do* use full-on model cities, e.g. [Ano Hana](http://otakumode.com/sp/visit_japan/seichi-junrei/s005) and [Ano Natsu de Matteru](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=497109).

<sup>3</sup> I believe I translated that well enough, but school nomenclature confuses me at times - the name in Japanese is 小川町立小川小学校 下里分校, lit. "Ogawa-machi Municipal Ogawa Elementary School, Shimosato Branch School".

<sup>4</sup> For details and comparison shots, see e.g. [this blog post](http://tsurebashi.blog123.fc2.com/blog-entry-320.html).